# Integers won't store in vector

Tags: c++, class

I've created this code, where users can input the day and int to store in a class. but unfortunately my value of int can't be stored in the vector attribute. I've tried debugging it and set a break point at  addValues(). it stored the value for a while. But after it looped the value seems to not be stored in the vector. can you guys please help me :)

you need to use this.

```
class Name_values
{
public:
  Name_values();                                    
  Name_values( const string&, const vector<int>& );  
  void add_value( const int& );
  void print_all( ) const;
  string get_name( ) const;
private:
  string name;
  vector<int> values;

}
```

The users can input it as many times as they want until name="q".

input = Montag.
input = 45.

input = Montag.
input = 23.

input = Di.
input = 12.

output.

Name: Montag.
Value: 45, 23.
Name: Dienstag.
Value: 12.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <exception>
using std::vector;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::ostream;
using std::endl;

class Name_values{
public:
    Name_values();
    Name_values(const string& name, const vector<int>& values);
    Name_values(const string& name, const string& name2);
    void addTag (Name_values& tag);
    void addValue(const int& value);
    void printAll();
    bool checkValue(const string& name,const int& value);
    void menu();
    string getName()const{return name;}
    string getName2()const{return name2;}
    vector<int> getVector()const{return values;}
    vector <Name_values> getWeek();
    
private:
    string name;
    string name2;
    int value;
    vector<int> values;
    vector<Name_values>week;
};

Name_values::Name_values(){}
Name_values::Name_values(const string& name, const vector<int>& values): name(name), values(values){}
Name_values::Name_values(const string& name, const string& name2): name(name), name2(name2){}


void Name_values::addValue(const int& value){
    values.push_back(value);
}

void Name_values::printAll(){
    cout<<"Name: "<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"Value: ";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < values.size(); i++){
        cout<<values.at(i);
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for (Name_values tag: week){
        tag.printAll();
    }
}

void Name_values::addTag(Name_values &tag){
    week.push_back(tag);
}

bool Name_values::checkValue(const string& name,const int& value){
    for (Name_values tag : week){
        if (tag.getName() == name || tag.getName2()==name){
            tag.addValue(value);
            cout<< tag.getVector().size();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void Name_values::menu(){
    string name;
    int value = 0;
    while(true){
        cout<<"Name: ";
        cin>> name;
        if(name=="q"||name=="Q")
            break;
        cout<<"Value: ";
        cin>>value;
        if(checkValue(name, value)){
            continue;
        }
           else{
               cout<<"No Name!"<<endl;
               break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    Name_values week;
    Name_values mon("Montag", "Mo");
    Name_values die("Dienstag", "Di");
    Name_values mit("Mittwoch", "Mi");
    Name_values don("Donnerstag", "Don");
    Name_values fre("Freitag", "Fr");
    Name_values sam("Samstag", "Sa");
    Name_values son("Sontag", "So");
    week.addTag(mon);
    week.addTag(die);
    week.addTag(mit);
    week.addTag(don);
    week.addTag(fre);
    week.addTag(sam);
    week.addTag(son);
    week.menu();
    cout<<mon.getVector().size();
    for(int i : mon.getVector()){
        cout<<i;
    }
    //week.printAll();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please include input, output and expected output to the quesiton

Comment: Do you think there is some connection between the `week` variable in `main` and the `week` member variables of the `Name_values` instances, or that those members are the same object shared by all the instances?

Comment: BTW: it's usually a mistake to have a class that represents both one thing and a collection of those things. Make that two types. (Also, if you can't think of a more meaningful name for something than "Name_values", it's probably not a meaningful thing.)

Comment: so should I make vector<Name_values>week in a different class?

Comment: That could be one idea, yes.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the assignment. What was being asked there was to provide a way to store different values associated to a single day (so you have a "Monday" along with a bunch of numbers `45`,`23`,`128`,...). You now *also* tried to aggregate all of the different days to a week, which is not what the assignment asked for. Instead, try to only focus on the initial problem first and then if you feel like it, solve the other problem later. But for now mixing the two things together seems to be the major source of confusion here, so don't do that.

Comment: Can you give me a preview of how the code would look like

Comment: how can I make the code. if users input == Monday or Mo then add the value to the vector of Mon object